# lisp interpreter in python

Tags: python, shell, scripting, lisp, interpreter

I'm curious how a part of Peter Norvig's Lisp interpreter works. One can define functions in this Lisp interpreter...how does this work? I'm a beginner, and just would like a simple explanation.

There's one part that might be related where it says

```
elif x[0] == 'define':         # (define var exp)
        (_, var, exp) = x
```

http://norvig.com/lispy.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, `x[0]` is `define`, `x[1]` is the variable name, and `x[2]` is the expression. So, in Python, `_, var, exp = x` is a "destructuring assignment", which destructures the array `x` into its constituent elements, and assigns them to the variables on the left-hand side.

Comment: how does defining functions work though? how does the interpreter understand `(define (square x) (* x x))` ?

Comment: @tekknolagi: `(define (square x) (* x x))` is syntactic sugar for `(define square (lambda (x) (* x x)))`. It's pretty obvious here that `var` is `square` and `exp` is `(lambda (x) (* x x))`.

Comment: how does it hold the user defined function in memory and then use it when the user calls `(square 5)` ?

Comment: @tekknolagi: `lambda` creates a _function object_. In Scheme (just like in Python, JavaScript, etc.), functions are first-class: you can pass them around like other objects. Additionally (unlike other objects), you can call them.

Comment: how does it understand what to do when a user defines a function? i'm just not getting the `eval()` loop

Comment: @tekknolagi: It simply creates a Python lambda object that holds a reference to the expression given. When the Python lambda object is called (in the line `return proc(*exps)`), that stored expression is then passed into a recursive call to `eval`.

Comment: @tekknolagi: It's a naming convention for an _unused variable_. i.e., it's just a placeholder for holding stuff that is simply thrown away.

Comment: what is the `*args` referring to?

Comment: @tekknolagi: The arguments passed to the Python lambda, of course. (Read up on how to use variable-arity functions in Python.)